# Getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 in flask

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, load

I want to display images in an grid and because of this error i am unable to see the image

[image: not able to see the images]

Here is my file structure

[image: File Structure]

```js
let selectedCategory = "Flag"; // Set a default category
let selectedIcons = [];

// Function to calculate Manhattan distance between two points
function manhattanDistance(point1, point2) {
  return Math.abs(point1.x - point2.x) + Math.abs(point1.y - point2.y);
}

// Function to display icons based on the selected category
function displayIcons() {
  const categorySelect = document.getElementById('categorySelect');
  selectedCategory = categorySelect.value; // Update selectedCategory
  const grid = document.getElementById('grid');
  const signupForm = document.getElementById('signupForm');

  // Clear existing icons
  grid.innerHTML = '';
  signupForm.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the signup form

  // Load and display icons from the selected category folder
  for (let i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
    const imgElement = document.createElement('img');
    imgElement.src = `{{ url_for('static', filename='GBAS') }}/${selectedCategory}/${selectedCategory}${i}.png`;
    const gridCell = document.createElement('div');
    gridCell.className = 'grid-cell';
    gridCell.appendChild(imgElement);
    gridCell.addEventListener('click', () => handleIconClick(i));
    grid.appendChild(gridCell);
  }
}

// Function to handle icon click and store selected icons
function handleIconClick(iconIndex) {
  selectedIcons.push(iconIndex);
  if (selectedIcons.length === 2) {
    const selectedIconsInput = document.getElementById('selectedIconsInput');
    const selectedCategoryInput = document.getElementById('selectedCategoryInput');
    selectedIconsInput.value = JSON.stringify(selectedIcons);
    selectedCategoryInput.value = selectedCategory;
    showSignupForm();
  }
}

// Function to show the signup form
function showSignupForm() {
  const signupForm = document.getElementById('signupForm');
  signupForm.style.display = 'block';
}

// Add an event listener to the dropdown box to trigger icon display
document.getElementById('categorySelect').addEventListener('change', displayIcons);

// Add an event listener to the signup form to handle submission
document.getElementById('signupForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fetch('/signup', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new FormData(this),
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(message => alert(message))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
});

// Initial display of icons
displayIcons();
```

```css
/* Set a beautiful background for the entire page */

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

body {
  background-color: #e1eaea;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


/* Style for the dropdown box */

select {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #e6e9eb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
}


/* Center the dropdown */

.dropdown-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/* Define the grid container for displaying icons */

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  /* 4 columns with fixed width */
  grid-gap: 10px;
  /* Gap between grid cells */
  border: 2px solid #5995bc;
  /* Blue border around the grid */
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  /* Add some padding to the grid container */
  background-color: #faf4f4;
}


/* Define the grid cell styles (icons) */

.grid-cell {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /* Black border around each cell */
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  /* Add cursor pointer to indicate selection */
}

img {
  width: 70px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.gradient-background {
  background: linear-gradient(300deg, #b40208, #ffffff);
  background-size: 180% 180%;
  animation: gradient-animation 18s ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">



<h1>Select any two icons and describe the sequence of arrow commands</h1>
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <!-- Dropdown box for selecting categories -->
  <select id="categorySelect">
    <option value="Flag">Flag</option>
    <option value="Numbers">Numbers</option>
    <option value="Transportation">Transportation</option>
    <option value="Alphabets">Alphabets</option>
  </select>
</div>
<!-- Grid container for displaying icons based on the selected category -->
<div class="grid-container" id="grid"></div>
<!-- Sign up form -->
<form id="signupForm" action="/signup" method="POST" style="display: none;">
  <input type="hidden" id="selectedIconsInput" name="selectedIcons" value="">
  <input type="hidden" id="selectedCategoryInput" name="selectedCategory" value="">
  <label for="arrowInput">Enter the sequence of arrow commands (e.g., ↑, ↓, ←, →): </label>
  <input type="text" id="arrowInput" name="arrowInput" required>
  <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: so where in your "File Structure" are `Flag2.png`, `Flag3.png`, `Flag4.png`, `Flag5.png`, `Flag6.png`, `Flag9.png`, `Flag10.png`, `Flag12.png`, `Flag14.png`, `Flag13.png`, `Flag16.png`, `Flag15.png`, `Flag11.png`, `Flag8.png`, and `Flag7.png`

Comment: You can see which image url it is trying to load by hovering over the link « flag-1.png:1 » in the console. Or go to the network tab where you will find it too. So, what is the actual link?

Comment: Please [edit] the snippet I made you and remove all irrelevant code and replace the templating with what it rendered. You can show the `{{ }}` code seperately